# Is it safe to use Class level Predicate in Multithreading Application

Tags: multithreading, java-8, predicate, class-variables

I am trying to understand if there could be any issues with Predicate defined at class level in multithreaded application. ? We have defined such predicates in our services and using them up different methods of same class. Currently we have not seen any issue but I am curious to understand our class level Predicate object is going to function. will there be any inconsistency  in the behaviour?
eg:

```java
class SomeClass{

      Predicate<String> check = (value) -> value.contains("SomeString");
      // remaning impl. of the class.
}
```

Comment: No issues. These are effectively pure functions which dont modify the input and have no side effects.

Comment: What problem do you think there will be? How do you think it works?

Answer (score 0):

The predicate in your example is categorically thread-safe.  It is calling a method on an intrinsicly thread-safe (and immutable) object.

This does not generalize to all predicates though.  For example

```
Predicate<StringBuilder> check = (value) -> value.indexOf("SomeString") >= 0;
```

is not thread-safe.  Another thread could mutate the contents of the `StringBuilder` argument while this predicate is checking it.  The predicate could also be vulnerable to memory model related inconsistencies.

(The `StringBuilder` class is not thread-safe; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).)

---

It is not clear what you mean by "class level".  Your example shows a predicate declared as a regular field, not a `static` (class level) field.

With a variable declared as a (mutable) instance field, it is difficult to reason about the thread-safety of the field in isolation.  This can be solved by declaring the field as `final`.